# A machine produces B unit goods in A hours...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

A machine produces $b$ unit goods in $a$ hours. How many hours does this machine need to produce $b\cdot c$ unit goods?

Comment: So that's $b$ units in $a$ hours, $2b$ units in $2s$ hours, $3b$ units in $3a$ hours ... See the pattern?

Comment: So its $a⋅c$ units good in $b⋅c$ hours.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes $a\cdot c$ hours.

The rate of goods are being produced is $\frac{b}{a}$. We need to find the amount of time that has to pass for which we produce at this rate in order to achieve $b\cdot c$ units produced.

That is, you want to solve this for $t$:

$$b\cdot c = \frac{b}{a} t$$

We get $t= a\cdot c$.

Answer (score 0):

$\because$ Machine produces $b$ unit goods in $a$ hours

$\therefore$ Machine would produce $1$ unit goods in $\frac{a}{b}$ hours

$\therefore$ Machine would produce $b\cdot c$ unit goods in $\frac{a}{{b}}\times b\cdot c$

Machine would need **$a\cdot c$** hours.

---

**Alternate Method**:

We observe that the number of goods produced $(N)$ is directly proportional to time $(t)$ i.e. in more time more number of goods will be produced.

$N \propto t$

$N = k\cdot t$ ($k$ is variation constant). (eq (1))

$\therefore k = \frac{N}{t} = \frac{b}{a}$

We have to find $t$, so $t= \frac{N}{k}$ (from eq(1)).

Now plugging the value of $N \& k$, we get $t= \frac{N}{k}=\frac{b\cdot c}{\frac{b}{a}} = \boxed{ac}$.

You should definitely check [this](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/algebra/algebra-ii/rational-expressions/proportion-direct-variation-inverse-variation-joint-variation) method of variation.